# Suppressing error message popups in CDHtmlDialog doesn't work with IE 11

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, mfc

I'm not sure if it's something new to IE 11, or maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm embedding an IE web browser via the MFC's `CDHtmlDialog` class (that internally encapsulates the `IWebBrowser2` interface.)

So I do the following:

```
BOOL CMyDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog();

    //Disable JavaScript errors
    m_pBrowserApp->put_Silent(VARIANT_TRUE);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

but I still get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think [Bugs in IE 11 (11.0.1)](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/809357/bugs-in-ie-11-11-0-1)

Comment: No, no. I'm not talking about that specific Google error. I want to know why can't I disable showing of debugging error popups in an embedded IE?